# Is that a bug in Integrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Why does the result of `Integrate` become negative?
[image: code]

```
L = 30;
BL1 = 26.703537555508106`;

b1 =(-E^-BL1 + Cos[BL1] + Sin[BL1])/(Cos[BL1] - Sin[BL1] - E^BL1) *
    (E^(BL1*x/L) + Cos[BL1*x/L] + Sin[BL1*x/L]) + Cos[BL1*x/L] -
    Sin[BL1*x/L] + E^(-BL1*x/L);

(4*BL1^4 + 1)*2*Integrate[b1^2, {x, 0, L}]
```

Comment: Try evaluating it with `BL1 = Rationalize[26.703537555508106, 0]`

Comment: oh no ~BL1 = Rationalize[26.703537555508106, 0] out for
Exponent is out of bounds for function PolynomialGCD

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the precision of the numbervalues:

```
Integrate[SetPrecision[b1^2, 50], {x, 0, L}]
(*29.999999999848 + 0.*10^-18 I*)
```

or integrate numerically

```
NIntegrate[b1^2, {x, 0, L} , WorkingPrecision -> 50]
(*29.999999999848227087199100665744175383806233703766*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or to avoid the GCD problem Integrate before introducing the BL1 constant

```
Clear[BL1];
L = 30;
b1 =(-E^-BL1 + Cos[BL1] + Sin[BL1])/(Cos[BL1] - Sin[BL1] - E^BL1) *(E^(BL1*x/L) +
Cos[BL1*x/L] + Sin[BL1*x/L]) + Cos[BL1*x/L] - Sin[BL1*x/L] + E^(-BL1*x/L);
Integrate[b1^2,{x,0,L}]/.BL1->26.703537555508106`

(*30.*)
```